# How to pop up the YouTube Video player on the foreground

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a YouTube video player embedded for videos in my website and I want the player to have the same effect as the IMDB website player (http://www.imdb.com/)

I understood and did one part i.e. dimming the background using the following code :

```
 var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                var element = document.getElementById("dim")
                element.style.backgroundColor =  'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
                        done = true;
            }
        }
```

But what I cannot do is how in the IMDB website the video pops up along with the background getting dim.

My full code :

```
<div id="dim>
<div id="player"></div>
    <script>
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'XGSy3_Czz8k',
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                var element = document.getElementById("dim")
                element.style.backgroundColor =  'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)';
                        done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You could consider on using fancybox: [link](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), you'll also need to add the jQuery library. As i see, in IMDB, they're using something that looks quite like fancybox (or any other modal javascript library), except for the small playlist below the video.

Comment: try using a CDN instead. Here is the library and the css from cdnjs.com: [fancybox.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js) and the css: [fancybox.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css) ... here is also a mini-demo in jsfiddle: [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/ze01r2oh/), let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

By Looking at IMDB example, it seems there is a hidden container that is the same Height as the entire site, in that container is where they pop up the video player.

i used GSAP to animate the pop up:

```
$('.video-btn').on('click',function(){

    $('.video-overlay').addClass('is-on');

    TweenMax.from('#vid',.6,{scale:0});
});
```

The main reason for GSAP is because any children of the #vid Container scales along with the parent, so you can have your controls, thumbnails or whatever you want and it will scale with it. I would only recommend to dynamically add your video after the pop up finished animating. If you scale/animate video, the animation may stutter.

here is the quick demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/keinchy/4Lk7wj6o/1/

hope this helps, cheers.